# SFMC API Integration using Python

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforce1-app, python

Getting the following error when trying to integrate SFMC using Python. Can someone help me with this?

```
File "/Users/abhinavagrawal/Desktop/sfmc_new.py", line 17, in <module>
    'account_id': '110007287'
  File "/Users/abhinavagrawal/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/FuelSDK/client.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.configure_client(get_server_wsdl, params, tokenResponse)
  File "/Users/abhinavagrawal/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/FuelSDK/client.py", line 207, in configure_client
    self.refresh_token()
  File "/Users/abhinavagrawal/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/FuelSDK/client.py", line 275, in refresh_token
    self.refresh_token_with_oAuth2(force_refresh)
  File "/Users/abhinavagrawal/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/FuelSDK/client.py", line 326, in refresh_token_with_oAuth2
    raise Exception('Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided: ' + repr(r.json()))
Exception: Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided: {u'errorcode': 404, u'message': u'Not Found', u'documentation': u'https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm'}
```

```
import FuelSDK
import ET_Client

stubObj = FuelSDK.ET_Client(
      False, False,
      {
         'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
          'clientid':'',
          'clientsecret':'',
          'defaultwsdl':'https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl',
          'authenticationurl': 'https://mcxqdjf10j-ts2tln1bh5s72fqnm.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token',
          #'baseapiurl':'https://mcxqdjf10j-ts2tln1bh5s72fqnm.rest.marketingcloudapis.com',
          'soapendpoint':'https://mcxqdjf10j-ts2tln1bh5s72fqnm.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx',
          'useOAuth2Authentication':'False',
          'applicationType':'server',
          'account_id': ''

      })


myClient = FuelSDK.ET_Client()
list = FuelSDK.ET_List()
list.auth_stub = myClient
response = list.get()

print 'Post Status: ' + str(response.status)
print 'Code: ' + str(response.code)
print 'Message: ' + str(response.message)
print 'Result Count: ' + str(len(response.results))
print 'Results: ' + str(response.results)
```

Comment: Based on the error, it sounds like the ClientID and Secret (think username/password) for connecting to your SFMC APP are not found where expected. `{u'errorcode': 404, u'message': u'Not Found',...`

Comment: @Gortonington I am using the following code. Have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have deliberately removed the `clientId` and `clientSecret` values from your code example and are including these in your call.

You just need to set `useOAuth2Authentication` to `True` as you are using OAuth 2.0, not the legacy OAuth 1.0 flow.